# Utility started from python code doesn't write in file

Tags: python

I have two utilities written in C++, TCP/IP server and client that I have used for years.
Server opens designated file and waits for client to connect. After connection has been established the server starts to send file's content. The client receives it and saves in a file.
Now, I want to write a python script to start both application and wait for them to finish. After that script will do some other work. It is written for Windows.
It is my first script in python. And my first problem is that I can see that both applications have started and connected to each other. I can see it because two DOS windows appears and show messages that inform me about connection.
However, I don't see a file, which has to be created by the client. What is wrong. Code is very simple and follows.

```
import subprocess 

p = subprocess.Popen('C:\MyProjects\exes\FeedSender_exe\FeedSender.exe C:\MyProjects\exes\FeedSender_exe\FeedSender.ini') 
print "Start1"
p1 = subprocess.Popen('C:\MyProjects\exes\FeedReaderFileProcessor\FeadReaderi41.exe C:\MyProjects\exes\FeedReaderFileProcessor\Config.ini') 
print "Start2"

for line in p.stdout.readlines(): 
    print line, 
retval = p.wait()
print "Finish1"
retval = p1.wait() 
print "Finish2"
```

Comment: Put `r` in front of the command line strings. I.e. `Popen(r'C:\MyProjects\...')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will probably help to set the subprocess's current working directory.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(r'C:\MyProjects\exes\FeedSender_exe\FeedSender.exe C:\MyProjects\exes\FeedSender_exe\FeedSender.ini',
        cwd=r'C:\MyProjects\exes\FeedSender_exe')
```

Depending on how you set up your programs, the output file should show up in `C:\MyProjects\exes\FeedSender_exe`. I obviously can't get your programs, so I can't test this.

Comment: When I try to upvote it says I don't have privilege enough. However, I answered positively question "Was this post useful to you?"

Comment: You still should be able to accept the answer since you're the one who asked the question. I forgot about needing reputation to upvote.  

Also, did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Add double '\' as so:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('C:\\MyProjects\\exes\\FeedSender_exe\\FeedSender.exe C:\\MyProjects\\exes\\FeedSender_exe\\FeedSender.ini')
```

Comment: Better and easier to read if you put `r` in front to make the string raw, see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings), i.e. `Popen(r'C:\MyProjects\...')`.

Comment: Although in this particular case it doesn't matter, since in python, "Unlike Standard C, all unrecognized escape sequences are left in the string unchanged, i.e., _the backslash is left in the string._" http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html

Comment: Thank you, any knowledge is useful to me now. However, it doesn’t help really because both applications start properly and print all proper messages as they do when started manually. They inform me that connection took place. But client doesn’t create file.